# JPA : Query with boolean argument in embeddable object not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've been trying to update from Hibernate 5.3.18 / Spring JPA 2.1.21 to Hibernate 6.1.5 / Spring JPA 3.0.0. Everything worked well before this update. Some simple tests that have worked so far now fail. Here is one of them that gives me headaches.

Let's start with an entity (I'll skip a thing or two to keep it simple):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="my_entity")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  protected MyEmbeddable myEmbeddable;

  ...
  /* Some other stuff like equals() and hashcode() */
  ...

  public MyEmbeddable getMyEmbeddable() {
    return myEmbeddable;
  }

  public void setMyEmbeddable(MyEmbeddable myEmbeddable) {
    this.myEmbeddable = myEmbeddable;
  }
}
```

```
@Embeddable
public class MyEmbeddable implements Serializable {
  @Column(name = "boolean_value", precision = 1)
  @Convert(converter = BooleanConverter.class)
  private Boolean booleanValue;

  public Boolean getBooleanValue() {
    return booleanValue;
  }

  public void setBooleanValue(Boolean booleanValue) {
    this.booleanValue = booleanValue;
  }
}
```

Note that a `BooleanConverter`is defined to map 1/0 to `true`/`false` (legacy database).

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
  @Query("SELECT e FROM MyEntity e "
      + "WHERE e.myEmbeddable.booleanValue = :booleanValue")
  List<MyEntity> findByBooleanValue(@Param("booleanValue") Boolean booleanValue);

  /* The following methods were added for new tests after upgrade. They won't be kept. */
  List<MyEntity> findByMyEmbeddableBooleanValue(Boolean booleanValue);

  List<MyEntity> findByMyEmbeddableBooleanValueIsTrue();

  List<MyEntity> findByMyEmbeddableBooleanValueIsFalse();
}
```

Now, before the update, `MyEntityRepository.findByBooleanValue()` was working perfectly. I created the following test:

1. A `MyEntity` entity was created. Its `MyEmbeddable` object was created with `booleanValue = true`.
2. The entity was saved in a database.
3. A test checked that `MyEntityRepository.findByBooleanValue(true)` was returning a list with one entity.

Since the update, this test failed. What I've observed so far when debugging this test:

1. Calling `MyEntityRepository.findByBooleanValue(true)` returns an empty list.
2. Calling `MyEntityRepository.findAll()` returns a list with the entity. In its embedded object, `booleanValue = true`.
3. Calls to `MyEntityRepository.findByMyEmbeddableBooleanValue(true)` or `MyEntityRepository.findByMyEmbeddableBooleanValueIsTrue()` return empty lists.
4. Calls to `MyEntityRepository.findByMyEmbeddableBooleanValue(false)` or `MyEntityRepository.findByMyEmbeddableBooleanValueIsFalse()` return a list with the entity (with `myEmbeddable.booleanValue = true`).

And, to make it more complicated, if I change the test and set `myEntity.myEmbeddable.booleanValue = false`, the test runs with success.

My question: what am I missing here? Why can't `true` work in these tests? Any clues?

Regards

Francois

Comment: Check generated sql with parameters

Comment: What code changes did you make to get it to run with JPA 3.0 and the other versions? You would have had to change from javax to Jakarta.

Comment: @Chris Of course I had to replace javax with jakarta, otherwise it wouldn't compile. I made similar adjustments in the ,`persistence.xml` file. Another change: I had to remove the annotation `@Embedded` in my entities. Normally, this annotation was added when defining `protected MyEmbeddable myEmbeddable`, but the embeddable object was not instanciated, therefore made Hibernate throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @viking I'll have a look.

Comment: Removing the Embedded annotation shouldn't change how Hibernate handles the mapping - and is worth looking into, especially since this mapping is the one that seems to be behaving differently for you. JPA requires providers handle null embedded properties, so this would be a hibernate bug if it is behaving differently with just a javax->jakarta annotation change, and removing the annotation should have it (according to the spec) default to operate the same as if the @Embedded is there.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-6/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.